# how to play rmvb files on windows vista?

Tags: video, encoding, rmvb

What codec or player is needed to play .RMVB files on Windows Vista?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[KMPlayer](http://kmplayer.en.softonic.com/) will do it with its internal codec pack. Besides, I recommend you to install [CCCP](http://www.cccp-project.net/) which is a simple playback pack for Windows with the goal of supporting the majority of video formats in use today.

Comment: CCCP is what i wanted

Answer (score 3):

If you (justly) don't like the invasive Real Player, there's always [Real Alternative](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/Real_Alternative.htm), which will allow you to play RealMedia files without having to install RealPlayer/RealOne Player.

Answer (score 3):

**[SMPLayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/)** will playback RMVB out of the box, no external codecs required.

[image]

*SMPlayer is open source and free; a portable version is available.*

Answer (score 2):

The format was created by the people who make [RealPlayer](http://www.real.com/), so it will play the file. It can also be played in [VLC](http://videolan.org) and [Media Player Classic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/guliverkli/).

Comment: VLC's real media capabilities are rather poor, MPC won't play them at all unless the required codec is installed.

Answer (score 2):

vlc cannot play .rmvb format. u need real player to play this.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously [Real Player](http://www.real.com/) would play that ..
Or the other alternative is to use a [converter](http://www.rmvbcodec.com/rmvbconvertersetup.exe) to get it in desired/*playable* format

or else look for some codec you'll get it with very little effort doing google search ..